# Can I day trade during the settlement period in a cash account?

Tags: day-trading

I'm a beginner at trading. Can I day trade during the settlement period in my cash account?

Answer (score 1):

In the U.S. and in a cash account, you can trade any time you want as long as it is with settled funds.

Answer (score 0):

Beginning with settled funds in a cash account, trades can be buy-sell-buy but the next sell would be a good-faith violation if it were done before the previous sell had settled.